# Vertical scrolling columns with different speeds

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to create an interface with 3 columns, each having mixed content (text, image, and video), and would like to have them scroll vertically with different speeds at the same time. Is there a relatively simple way of accomplishing this with html, css, and/or javascript?

PS. I know about the parallax scrolling, but the implementations I came across seem to be mostly about using images as background to create a dimensional illusion.

Comment: If you still need additional help you might try out the answer here to a very similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8950111/how-do-i-scroll-a-column-at-a-different-speed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like: http://jsfiddle.net/KVWuS/.

```
$.fn.makeScroll = function(speed) {
    var elem = this,
        i = 0;

    setInterval(function() {
        elem.scrollTop(i++); // increment scroll top
    }, speed); // run every 'speed' ms (so lower is faster)
};
```

You can enable it like:

```
$('div:eq(0)').makeScroll(75); // moderate speed
```

Comment: This answer is very valid and good. I am not the downvoter but will level pimvdb's score until an explanation is provided.

Comment: Thanks @pimvdb, this is pretty close to what I am looking for - now, can I control this behavior with the native scrolling of the browser (when I use the mouse wheel to scroll, this will be the way these columns would scroll)?

Comment: @Engin Erdoğan: Do you mean you want to change the speed of manual scrolling? I'm not sure, but I'll fiddle around.

Comment: I want the speed of browser scrolling to be different in all 3 columns. The behavior I want is identical to what you put in JSfiddle, except I want that behavior to be triggered with scrolling through up/down keys or mouse wheel.

Comment: @Engin Erdoğan: This is the best I could come up with, but it's quite hackish: http://jsfiddle.net/pimvdb/KVWuS/1/.

Comment: Thanks pimvdb, that is indeed a bit buggy, but I got some ideas from it.

Answer (score 1):

You want to *actually* scroll the content?

```
$('.column').animate({
    scrollTop: $('.column').height() - $(window).height()
}, 1000);
```

This will scroll your column down in 1 second. Adjust the speed per column.

**EDIT:**

I was assuming your columns were the height of the window. If not, you'll have to adjust the `scrollTop`.

Comment: thanks Joseph, I should have specified, I am trying to get mousewheel to trigger this behavior, any ideas?

Comment: Not sure I fully understand what you're trying to do. Are you saying that you don't want it to automatically scroll, but rather that when the user scrolls, the scrolling speed should be different on each one of the columns?

Comment: Exactly, with user scrolling. And I am trying to make it so that the columns scroll simultaneously, with different speeds. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

I think a simple workaround would be to create 3 div Elements with the following Attributes:

overflow: hidden;
width: x px (fixed width)
height: x px (fixed height)
top: 0px; 
left: x px;

Then you have to capture the onscroll event and set the top-Attribute.

E.g.

div1: top: -100px

div2: top: -300px

div3: top: -500px

I hope my description is clear.. :)
That should work