# How do I scroll a column at a different speed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I have two columns, `#photos` and `#text`. My `#photos` column is longer and logically holds some images. When I scroll the page, I like the `#photos` column to scroll faster than the `#text` column, so that both columns align at the bottom.

I use jQuery's `$(window).scroll()` to update the `#photos` column:

```
$("#photos").css("top", Math.round(targetY));
```

How do I calculate targetY?

I know it probably has something to do with `$(document).height()`, `$("#photos").height()` and `$(window).scrollTop()`, but I can't figure out the formula.

Comment: So, how many scroll-bars are there? Three? Or two?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without a bit more code to look at, I can't really suggest changes to make directly to your code but I've managed to mock up a working version of what you're perhaps looking for with the following [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZCe2N/).

I've also broken down the equation into parts to make it easier to see what's going on.

So as you scroll the `text` div, the `photos` div scrolls at the same ratio depending on the height of the two containers.

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#textScroll').scroll(function(){
        var textDiff = $('#text').height() - $('#textScroll').height();
        var textDiffRatio = (1 / textDiff) * $('#textScroll').scrollTop();
        var photosDiff = $('#photos').height() - $('#photosScroll').height();
        var photosScrollTop = textDiffRatio * photosDiff;
        $('#photosScroll').scrollTop(photosScrollTop);
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="textScroll" style="width:100px; height:100px; overflow:auto;">
    <div id="text">
        Text 1<br />
        Text 2<br />
        Text 3<br />
        Text 4<br />
        Text 5<br />
        Text 6<br />
        Text 7
    </div>
</div>
<div id="photosScroll" style="width:100px; height:100px; overflow:auto;">    
    <div id="photos">
        Photos 1<br />
        Photos 1<br />
        Photos 2<br />
        Photos 2<br />
        Photos 3<br />
        Photos 3<br />
        Photos 4<br />
        Photos 4<br />
        Photos 5<br />
        Photos 5<br />
        Photos 6<br />
        Photos 6<br />
        Photos 7<br />
        Photos 7
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope it helps you solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what I needed. Also thanks for breaking it down, I understand now. You're very clever.